# Total number of iterations through loops?

Tags: java, series

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j <= n; j++) {

    }
}
```

How do I figure out the number of iterations through these loops as a summation in terms of `n`?

Comment: Why not just make a counter and do it your self?

Comment: Why not plop it in to eclipse / whatever IDE and run in? Add other counters, log messages, etc, and see for yourself.

Comment: roughly there are n for every n.

Comment: `O(n^2)`, or more accurately, around `(n^2-n)/2`...

Comment: Even through this was terribly stated, it's not a bad question. Next time, try to take the time to state your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't run the code, you can look at the for loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
for(int j = i+1; j <= n; j++)
```

The first loop runs `n-1` times.
The second loop runs `n-i-1` times (for each i).

So the total loop runs is the summation from 0 to n-2 of `n-i-1`, or `sigma(i=0,i<n-2,n-i-1)`.

- If `n=0` it loops 0 times.
- If `n=1` it loops 0 times.
- If `n=2` it loops 2 times.
- If `n=3` it loops 5 times.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. Not sure why it got down voted even when I specifically asked for a series implementation. If I wanted to print the output I would have done so. Ignorance is bliss

Comment: @user3001301 I noticed you have not accepted answers to any of your questions. If this answer helped you consider upvoting or accepting. It helps the community know which answers answer the question. Plus, it gives the asker and answerer a small amount of reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way to approach this:

```
int numMult = 0;    
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j <= n; j++){
        c[i][j] = a[i][j] * b[i][j];
        numMult++;
    }
}
System.out.println(numMult);
```

Comment: I think the downvote happened before you added `numMult`

Comment: Downvote was pre-edit (retracted now). I thought your answer was being facetious in that it seemed to be just a reproduction of the OP's code.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I fatfingered enter key before I was done.